# Access to CodeIgniter app from desktop application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have write a php application based on CodeIgniter. This app allow to manager software license. The user can buy a software license and admin can control it.
Now I want check licesne details (saved on server) from my software. To do it I need contact my CodeIgniter application from my software:

1. My software call my CodeIgniter application if user license data are valid;
2. My CodeIgniter check on DB and sen a response to my software;

So to this I need POST or GET data to a URL of CodeIgniter application, but how can I avoid authentication? When call my URL CodeIgniter application call me user authentication, this is ok but in this case I'd like avoid it.

What is the best solution?

Comment: "When call my URL CodeIgniter application call me user authentication..."
What?

Comment: @Kisaragi if I try to call (ex from browser) a uel like: http://www.example.com/index.php/users/check (this is only an example of CodeIgniter url) CodeIgniter show the authentication form. I'd like avoid this only for some url address of CodeIgniter application.